# jQuery loop through table and get element

Tags: php, jquery, json, forms

i've got some form input elements in an html table like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    ....
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="n_time" id="5030c9261eca0" value="2012" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="n_name" id="5030c9261eca0" value="a name" /></td>
        <td><textarea name="n_comment" id="5030c9261eca0">bla</textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

now, i need to send this form data using `$.post` to my PHP processing page
which looks something like

```
if($_POST['data']){
    $array = json_decode($_POST['data']);

}
```

so i need to get all my form elements and somehow made then into JSON

and this is what i did:

```
// assume i can get 5030c9261eca0 from my predefined vars...
$my_array = $("#5030c9261eca0").map(function () { return $(this).is("input")?$(this).val():$(this).text(); } );
//now convert
JSON.stringify($my_array);
// the conversion failed with : Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

this error poped up:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

how do i fix this?

also, if i do regluar HTTP post via HTML forms, i can recieve form data like `$_POST['n_name']` in PHP if i have a HTML form element with attribute `n_name`, how can i accomplish the same with the above?

Comment: You should NEVER use the same ID multiple times on a page. Use a class instead

Comment: If you're going to use ajax to post the form, you can try $('#formId').serialize()

Comment: So what value are you getting in converting the POSTed data to JSON? It seems to me you would be best served just using `$('#formid').serialize()` to get your form data ready to POST. And would have one less step in PHP to get to your POST data.

Comment: in my original HTML table, i do not have the <form> tag, so i just need to add the tag to make it work with `$('#formid').serialize()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First loop through all `tr`, then loop trought all `input,textarea` and push gathered values to array.

```
var data = [];      
$('table tr').each(function(){
    var row = {};
    $(this).find('input,textarea').each(function(){
        row[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });
    data.push(row);
});

// now you can use "data" :)
```

Example `data`:

```
[0][n_time] = foo
[0][n_name] = bar
[0][n_comment] = 123
[1][n_time] = foo
[1][n_name] = bar
[1][n_comment] = 123
...
```

jQuery:

```
$.post("test.php", { 'mydata': data } );
```

PHP:

```
foreach($_POST['mydata'] as $row) {
    echo $row['n_name'];
}
```

---

It's good idea to convert it to jQuery function:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.tableData = function() {
    var data = [];      
    $(this).find('tr').each(function(){
        var row = {};
        $(this).find('input,textarea').each(function(){
            row[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        });
    });
    return data;
  }
})( jQuery );

// Usage:

$.post("test.php", { 'mydata': $('table').tableData() } );
```

Comment: after some testing, the data will always show empty(data.length = 0), any ideas why?

Comment: My fault. Just remove `if(row.length)`

Answer (score 1):

You have two different variables with the exact same ID, *5030c9261eca0*.  An ID should be unique for a given HTML page.

Give each element a unique ID.

Instead, give each element that you want to locate a shared class, e.g. *needToPost*, and use that class:

```
$my_array = $(".needToPost").map(function () { return $(this).is("input")?$(this).val():$(this).text(); } );
```