# Storing jquery appended value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

I have a html form where i append few elements like, when user select multiple countries from list jquery run through the selected lists and create a set of  form fields for each country.

Assume user selected USA, China and India, then form fields will be created for each of this countries giving id asn name as *countryName_indexValue, customeName_countryName_indexValue.*

**My question:**
I need to submit this appended elements values to mysql database through php when user fill and hits submit button. How do i do it? Please help me......

And the result is this

```
<form>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Country Name</td>
<td>Data01</td>
<td>Data02</td>
</tr>
</thead>

<!-- APPENDED ELEMENTS -->

<tbody>
<tr id="usa_0">
<td><input type="text" name="userCountry_usa_0" id="userCountry_usa_0"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="countryData01_usa_0" id="countryData01_usa_0"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="countryData02_usa_0" id="countryData02_usa_0"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="china_1">
<td><input type="text" name="userCountry_china_1" id="userCountry_china_1"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="countryData01_china_1" id="countryData01_china_1"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="countryData02_china_1" id="countryData02_china_1"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="india_2">
<td><input type="text" name="userCountry_india_2" id="userCountry_india_2"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="countryData01_india_2" id="countryData01_india_2"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="countryData02_india_2" id="countryData02_india_2"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>

</form>
```

Thank you..

Comment: Can i see the code what have you tried so that we can modify it if possile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what's the issue?  Are you running into issues when you submit the data?  Or are you struggling to handle the $_POST on the PHP side?

If it's handling the $_POST, I'd suggest changing your generated form fields to have ids of the form `userCountry[countryName][indexValue]` instead of `userCountry_countryName_indexValue`.

That way, when the form is submitted, the $_POST will consist of arrays, which you can then loop over to write to a DB, e.g. the $_POST would have something like:

```
$_POST['userCountry'] = array( 'usa' => array( '0' => 'someValue'),
                               'china' => array( '1' => 'someOtherValue'),
                               'india' => array( '2' => 'yetAnotherValue'),
                        )
```

Then you can loop over this, e.g.:

```
foreach($_POST['userCountry'] as $country=>$subArray) {
    //code here to insert data
}
```

Your current implementation could work with loops as well, as long as you loop over the whole $_POST object, checking each key, and looking for particular sub-strings, exploding on underscores, and then handling, but it'd be kind of ugly.

Comment: Thanks for replying..
The issue is that, if i have a custom field with unique id/name e.g name="fieldName", then i can have a $varName = $_POST['fieldName']; in my php page where i will send this variable to mysql query so that it can store the value in database.

But here i'm generating new set of field for the each selected country. So if user selects 50 countries each field will have a id and name like i listed above. At this situation, how do i handle the fields for there respective countries, like i need each country and its data to be entered as a new record in a mysql table.

Comment: @sravis - I've updated my answer with more detail as to how changing the ids of the generated form elements will allow you to loop through the form data to insert it into the DB.

Comment: Thanks for helping, now i'm able to loop through each field and store it in database. I found this very usefull for my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040425/jquery-loop-through-table-and-get-element

Answer (score -1):

On form submit event, or on element click You can send the input values with jQuery's .post() or .get() function to a php file.

Here are some basic and more complex exaples on how to use .post():
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

It is highly recommended that the php file contains the data validation, and after that you can issue an sql insert with php from there.

Comment: The question wasn't how to submit data via a form . . .